How to efficiently reinstate duplicates in pandas
So I have a big pandas dataframe, with lots of duplicate rows, that needs processing. I can remove the duplicates easily enough but, having processed the dataframe, what I need to do is reinstate the duplicates in the same position as they were originally. EDIT And with the same processing as has been applied to the row that they duplicate.
I am doing this using a dictionary that tracks structure of the rows in the original dataframe - the dictionary keys are the row indices of the unique rows and the values are lists of duplicates (so a row that has no duplicates just appears as i: [i] and a row that has multiple duplicates appears as i: [j, k, l, ...]).
The code below is a toy example that does the job (obviously in the real application the processing is a bit more complicated than addition and multiplication). However, in the real application the loop that builds the dictionary is very slow, because for each duplicate row, I have to find where the first occurrence of that row is.
I'm sure there must be an efficient way to do this, as Dataframe.duplicated() is really fast and that has to do a similar job. Any thoughts on how to implement this efficiently would be much appreciated. Thanks!
EDIT 2; In the toy example I am just processing the original data, but this is perhaps misleading - I need to apply machine learning code to the de-duplicated dataframe, then apply the reinstating of duplicated rows to the ML output. So (I think) I really need to keep track of where duplicates originated from, rather than just applying some processing to the duplicates and merging them.
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [0, 0]], columns=['X', 'Y'])
print(dataframe)

index = dataframe.index
duplicates_mask = dataframe.duplicated()
print(duplicates_mask)
duplicates_structure = {}
deduplicated_indices = {}
for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    duplicates_structure[i] = []
deduplicated_index = 0
for i, is_duplicate in enumerate(duplicates_mask):  # way too slow :(
    if is_duplicate:
        for j in range(i):
            if duplicates_mask[j]:  # j is a duplicate, don't bother checking
                continue
            if (dataframe.iloc[i] == dataframe.iloc[j]).all():
                duplicates_structure[j].append(i)
                break
    else:
        duplicates_structure[i].append(i)
        deduplicated_indices[i] = deduplicated_index
        deduplicated_index += 1
print(duplicates_structure)

# drop the duplicates
dataframe.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# do some processing on the data
dataframe['X'] += 1
dataframe['Y'] *= 2
print(dataframe)

# reinstate the structure with duplicates processed
dataframe_reinstated = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=['X', 'Y'])
for i in duplicates_structure:
    for j in duplicates_structure[i]:
        dataframe_reinstated.iloc[j] = dataframe.iloc[deduplicated_indices[i]]
print(dataframe_reinstated)

EDIT E.g. input:
   X  Y
0  0  1
1  0  0
2  1  0
3  1  1
4  0  0
5  1  1
6  1  2
7  0  0

Output (after adding 1 to column X and multiplying column Y by 2):
   X  Y
0  1  2
1  1  0
2  2  0
3  2  2
4  1  0
5  2  2
6  2  4
7  1  0


I think it will be more efficient to create a dictionary with results in a function that gets a row and just apply it
resutls_dict = {}
def run_calculation(row,result_dic):
get_key_from_row = f'{row[x]}{row[y]}'
if get_key_from_row in resutls_dict.keys():
return result_dic[get_key_from_row]
value = ML_function(inputs)
return result_dic[get_key_from_row] = value
return value

this is the same concept of e-motta
but with your full code so you can run and test it
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [0, 0]], columns=['X', 'Y'])
print(dataframe)

#add key to data so later we can join on 
dataframe['key'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(dataframe, index=False)
full_datafrme = dataframe.copy()
# drop the duplicates
dataframe.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# do some processing on the data
dataframe['X_process'] = dataframe['X'] + 1
dataframe['Y_process'] = dataframe['Y'] * 2
dataframe = dataframe.drop(['X','Y'], axis=1)
#join/merge the table by the key 
full_dataframe_results = pd.merge(full_datafrme, dataframe, on='key')
#change table columns names to return to origine after the processing 
full_dataframe_results = full_dataframe_results.drop(['X','Y','key'], axis=1)
full_dataframe_results = full_dataframe_results.rename(columns={"X_process": "X", "Y_process": "Y"})
print(full_dataframe_results)

I want to give you a different way that may be more efficient then join
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [0, 0]], columns=['X', 'Y'])
print(dataframe)

#add key to data so later we can join on
dataframe['key'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(dataframe, index=False)


results ={}

def function_process(row, result_dic):
    key = row['key']
    if key in result_dic:
        return result_dic[key]
    process_result = row['X'] + row['Y']
    result_dic[key] = process_result
    return process_result

dataframe['results'] = dataframe.apply(lambda x:function_process(x,results),axis=1)
print(dataframe)


Thanks so much @gal peled (and @e-motta) - I think that should work. The only problem I can foresee is that the full dataframe can have up to two thousand (and potentially more) floating point numbers, so concatenating all those values in the 'key' column would get a bit unmanageable. However, if I could find a hash function that will give a unique key for each unique row of data then that would work. Is there such a function in pandas (or elsewhere)?

yes I will edit answer to show how but it will look like this dataframe['key'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(dataframe, index=False)

Fantastic - thanks so much!

IIUC, You can use this approach:
dedup = dataframe.drop_duplicates()

dedup["X_processed"] = dedup["X"] + 1
dedup["Y_processed"] = dedup["Y"] * 2

dataframe = dataframe.merge(dedup)

dataframe = dataframe[["X_processed", "Y_processed"]].rename(
    columns={"X_processed": "X", "Y_processed": "Y"}
)

   X  Y
0  1  2
1  1  0
2  2  0
3  2  2
4  1  0
5  2  2
6  2  4
7  1  0


Thanks so much @e-motta, but see my edits to the original question - I need to keep track of the duplicate structure, rather than just excluding the duplicates temporarily.

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but you are not losing any information about the duplicates, as the original dataframe is unaltered before the merge.

Keep it simple, take advantage of the (unique) index. Split, do whatever you need and concat+reindex again:
duplicates_mask = dataframe.duplicated()

df_dup = dataframe[duplicates_mask]
df_no_dup = dataframe[~duplicates_mask]

# do whatever you have to do
# e.g. add 10 to the duplicates
df_dup = df_dup + 10

# then merge again
out = pd.concat([df_no_dup, df_dup]).reindex(dataframe.index)

Note that if the operation to perform is simple, you can modify in place with boolean indexing:
dataframe[duplicates_mask] += 10

If you need to use the whole input, combine_first:
duplicates_mask = dataframe.duplicated()

df_dup = dataframe[duplicates_mask]
df_no_dup = dataframe[~duplicates_mask]

# do whatever you have to do
dataframe['X'] += 1
dataframe['Y'] *= 2

# then combine again
out = df_dup.combine_first(dataframe).reindex(dataframe.index)

Output:
    X   Y
0   0   1
1   0   0
2   1   0
3   1   1
4  10  10
5  11  11
6   1   2
7  10  10


Thanks so much, @mozway, but I realise I didn't ask the question clearly enough. I need to replicate the processing of the unique entries to their duplicates. I've edited the question to make that clearer.

Also, perhaps the word "processing" is misleading. I need to run machine learning code on the de-duplicated dataframe and then apply the results to the whole dataframe. Sorry for not making that clear.

@Chris IIUC, check the third approach in my update
